# Data view SMS sent

Tags: marketing-cloud, sms, data-views

I want to track data related to SMS send, such as JobID, BatchID, SubscriberID, EventDate, similarly to what it can be done for Email send by using the **_Sent** data view for Email send.

Are there ways to get this data whitout using the sendlogging?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SFSE, please take some time to read [ask] and take the [tour]. Did you do some research prior to posting your question? Is there documentation on the subject, if there is, did you attempt anything? Please share any of the above mentioned details in your post, you wouldn't want others wasting time one things you already attempted, or doing the research for you? Demonstrate some level of effort/research when posting questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can query the "SMSMessageTracking" data view to get the additional data you want :)
The syntax can be seen under `Salesforce Help` > `Docs` > `Marketing Cloud Journeys and Automations`: [Data View: SMSMessageTracking](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_sms_message_tracking.htm&type=5).

Answer (score 0):

this is not possible to my knowledge. You can query sms subscriber data, https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/using_the_query_activity/data_views/data_view_subscribersms/

but not the sms'es sent

you can manually create reports from the mobile connect studio, which generates a csv file